# Error while connecting to PowerBi

Tags: sql-server, authentication, powerbi

I am trying to connect PowerBi to a local SQL Server instance.

It has previously worked with a direct Windows Authentication. I tried changing it to a SQL Server Authentication. No luck.

I have specified which login type it was referring to.

The error it reports: "We couldn't authenticate with the credentials provided". I logged in without issues on both authentication methods in SQL Server Management Studio - works perfectly.

What else can I try?

Comment: In File | Options and settings | Data source settings, you can go in and edit the credentials of your existing data sources.

Comment: I have been changing my credentials there, no luck. @Sami

Comment: You mean a local instance through the data gateway? Can you provide screenshots of your data source?